# Approximating Linear Equations from Measurements

Tags: approximation, least-squares, data-analysis

I've been working on a fascinating problem involving measurements that reveal a relationship between two variables, $t$ and $y$. I have a set of four data points: $(-1, 0)$, $(0, 1)$, $(1, 2)$, and $(2, 4)$. The first component corresponds to the $t$-values, while the second component corresponds to the $y$-values. My goal is to approximate a linear equation that describes the relationship $y(t)$.

I'd really appreciate some guidance on the next steps in my analysis. Here are the specific questions I have:

(a) By using the equation of a straight line, $kt + m = y$, along with the four data points, how can I set up an equation system $Ax = b$?

(b) How can I show that there is no exact solution to the equation system $Ax = b$?

(c) What's the process to formulate a least squares problem and find the least squares solution to $Ax = b$?

(d) Could someone explain how to calculate the differences in $y$ values between the measured data and the values predicted by the least squares fit?

Absolutely, linear regression is indeed a suitable approach for this scenario. Given the data points $\{(-1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 4)\}$, you can use linear regression to find the best-fit line in the form $y = mx + b$. The goal is to minimize the sum of squared vertical distances between the observed $y$ values and the values predicted by the line.

To formulate the linear regression problem, we can represent the data points as a matrix equation:

$$\begin{bmatrix}-1&1\\ 0&1\\ 1&1\\ 2&1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}m\\ b\end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix}0\\ 1\\ 2\\ 4\end{bmatrix}$$

Here, the matrix on the left represents the design matrix $X$, the vector on the right is the response vector $\mathbf{y}$, and $\mathbf{m} = [m, b]^T$ contains the coefficients we want to find.

To solve for $\mathbf{m}$ using the least squares solution, we can compute:

$$\mathbf{m} = (X^T X)^{-1} X^T \mathbf{y}$$

Once we have the values of $m$ and $b$, the best-fit line equation is $y = mx + b$, which can be used for approximating the relationship between $y$ and $t$.

I think it's important here to perform appropriate calculations to find the numerical values of $m$ and $b$ using the provided data.

Your insights and advice would be immensely helpful in guiding me through these steps. Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Do you understand the matrix equation? Than you should be able to solve it. Say exactly where you have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You probably will want to use [linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) to find a best-fit line, given these data points.  There are standard textbooks that explain all of these aspects of linear regression; there is little point in us repeating that here.  I suggest you spend some time studying this topic in textbooks on statistics.

Comment: I edited my post, is my approach correct?